# PCA and Constant-Zero Column Error

Tags: r

I have a question about PCA using the caret package and an error message I'm getting, "cannot rescale a constant/zero column to unit variance".

Consider two sets of similar code.  The first works just fine:

```
a = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, -1, -1, NA)
b = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, NA)
c = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  1,  0,  0)

df = data.frame(a, b, c)

trans = preProcess(df, method = c("center", "scale", "pca"))
```

The variance of each column can be seen as:

```
apply(df, 2, var, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Note that the variance of column "c" is 0.11

Let's say I change the ***second to last*** integer in column "c" to 1 instead of 0, and then run the same code:

```
a = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, -1, -1, NA)
b = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, NA)
c = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  1,  1,  0)

df = data.frame(a, b, c)

trans = preProcess(df, method = c("center", "scale", "pca"))
```

I get an error message:

```
Error in prcomp.default(x, scale = TRUE, retx = FALSE) : 
  cannot rescale a constant/zero column to unit variance
```

If you look at the variance for column c, it's 0.059:

```
apply(df, 2, var, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Can anyone please help me understand the difference between these two sets of code and why the second gives an error when the first does not?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PCA only uses complete observations. In your second definition of `df` above, a PCA analysis will drop the last row due to missingness. And column `c` is constant within the remaining rows.

Note: my answer is around PCA generally and not specific to the caret package.

Comment: You can also make it work by adding some noise to the data (and hopefully loose little or no signal), e.g. `df <- df + rnorm(17*3)`.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you both.  Is adding a bit of noise as you suggest common/suggested practice?  And what if the variable is a dummy variable with just 1 or 0 -- would adding some noise be problematic in that case?